# Assign char* to string without copying

Tags: c++, arrays, string, copy

this is quite a simple question, however I'm finding it tricky. I want to treat a `char*` as if it were a `std::string`, for instance:

```
    char *p = ...; // read a huge chuck from a file

    std::string s(p); // this is not what I want
```

So, if I use the constructor, I get a copy of p, which is a waste of memory and time. Is it possible somehow to avoid this, and "*assign*" the `std::string` content to a pre-existing address?

Any other idea is more than welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Why not read the huge chunk from a file into the `std::string` directly?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me.  What kinds of things do you want to do with the data that makes you want it to be a `string`?

Comment: The data is already in place in memory, for example with a memory mapped file. That's why I cannot have a `std::string` in the first place.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: std::string is an object, which expects more than a char*, so you can only copy it directly

Comment: std::string_view is what you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it possible somehow to avoid this, and "*assign*" the `std::string` content to a pre-existing address?

No.

However, you can assign it to a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view). Going forward, all uses of `std::string` *except to own memory* should be replaced by `std::string_view`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` does not *and cannot possibly* support this, as it owns the string buffer.

Which means that it will eventually have to free the memory, or reallocate it in case you change the string to have a different length. If not earlier, then it must do so when the program exits.

Now, what is `string` supposed to do with some unknown block of memory that it got via a pointer? Is this memory allocated on the heap or on the stack, or maybe readonly memory from the data segment? There is nothing `string` could possibly do that is valid and won't either leak or cause a crash in one or the other situation.

Comment: So, as `std::string` cannot do that, is `std::vector` a viable option? Of course I will need to write some additional functions, but if it's faster (by not copying) I would do that.

Comment: The same is true for `vector`, so no. Vector allocates, reallocates, owns, and eventually frees the store. Therefore it, too, has to copy the data in your `char*` buffer into its own store, there's no other way. It's not possible to own or free (or reallocate) a buffer if you don't know how it was allocated or whether it can be freed at all. Calling `allocator::deallocate` or `operator delete` for that matter (or `free`, which is usually the underlying mechanism) on something that wasn't allocated in the same way almost certainly causes a crash (freeing NULL being the only notable exception).

Comment: Thanks, that clarified my doubts a lot.

Comment: Why can't we do it the other way around? That is, if I know the length of the string to be read from file upfront, maybe I can resize the string to that value (to make sure it has got the proper amount of memory allocated internally) and then somehow ask the string for the pointer to its internal buffer to read the data directly into it? Inb4 calling it "unsafe" or something: it is not much safer than reading these data byte-by-byte and assigning to the string with its [] operator in a loop (just less cumbersome).

Answer (score 1):

No, because the `std::string` generally expects more than a `char*` can provide, most notably reallocation of the storage into totally different place of memory. Also a `std::string` isn't guaranteed to be null-terminated, it just provides a `begin()` and an `end()`.

But note that `std::string` and `char[]` have quite common interfaces:

- you can index them with numbers and obtain `chars`,
- you can call `std::begin` and `std::end` of them and get random access iterators, so that algorithms like `sort` can operate on them freely.

That's the core of C++ standard template library- containers and algorithms are separate, and the same algorithm can operate on a `std::string` and a `char[]`.

Of course `char*` isn't `char[]`, but OTOH a *pair* of `char*`s looks exactly like `begin(char[])` and `end(char[])`, so that enough allows you to connect it to STL utilities that work in term of random access iterators.

Answer (score 1):

**No** the wide-spreading `std::string` implementations do not implement a such feature. Even using the [`placement new()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax#Default_placement) because the internal members can change from one implementation to another, or from one version to another, or depending on some `#define`... There is also the option to provide your own `std::string` allocator, but this does not seem to be the way to deal with this kind of issue...

**Yes** some `string` implementations allow buffer reuse as the [`RFA_string` from Reuters Foundation API](https://customers.reuters.com/developer/Kits/RFA/CPlusPlus/RFA_CPlusPlus_ProductOverview.aspx).

This idea has already been treated on some other questions/answers:

- [initializing std::string from char* without copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361500)
- [How to reuse a string variable in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876920)
- [Dealing with char buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113178)
- [Memory-efficient C++ strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116040)

Moreover, there is also the [rope data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29) as for [SGI STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html) used by [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/algorithm/string/std/rope_traits.hpp)...

Answer (score -3):

Why not use `std::vector<char>` ? For example:

```
std::vector<char> data;
data.resize( size );  // resize this to how much you need 

char* p = &data[0];

// now you have a pointer to the internal data in std::vector
```

Comment: That seems to be the *opposite* of what OP wants.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @KonradRudolph, I'd like data to point to p, where p is pointer to an already allocated data.